# Jupyter notebook load modules installed by setup.py

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

I'm installing a C++ extension in the IPython notebook using setup.py. After it is installed it is not available in notebook cells, only after a restart. 
I`ve tried also

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

and it does not work (I believe it is used only for reloading already installed modules).
How can I make this new module visible in the IPython notebook without a restart? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I run the notebook in Google Colab